# React Native fetch error: "[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Network request failed]"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, react-native, expo

I am trying to make a request in react native using `fetch` function. I am using **expo**. When the function responsible for sending the request is called, I get this error:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Network request failed]
- node_modules\whatwg-fetch\dist\fetch.umd.js:473:29 in xhr.onerror
- node_modules\event-target-shim\dist\event-target-shim.js:818:39 in EventTarget.prototype.dispatchEvent
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:574:29 in setReadyState
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:388:25 in __didCompleteResponse
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\vendor\emitter\EventEmitter.js:190:12 in emit
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:436:47 in __callFunction
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:111:26 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:384:10 in __guard
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:110:17 in __guard$argument_0
* [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  SafeAreaView,
  Modal,
  Alert,
} from "react-native";
import { TextInput, Button } from "react-native-paper";
import * as ImagePicker from "expo-image-picker";
import * as Permissions from "expo-permissions";
const CreateEmployee = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [phone, setPhone] = useState("");
  const [salary, setSalary] = useState("");
  const [picture, setPicture] = useState("");
  const [position, setPosition] = useState("");
  const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);

  const submitData = () => {
    fetch("http://192.168.1.3:3000/send-data", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(name, email, phone, salary, picture, position),
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => console.log(data));
  };

  const runImagePicker = async () => {
    const { granted } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
    if (granted) {
      const data = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
        mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
        allowsEditing: true,
        Aspect: [1, 1],
        Quality: 0.5, //From the actual image
      });
      if (!data.cancelled) {
        let newFile = {
          uri: data.uri,
          type: `test/${data.uri.split(".")[1]}`,
          name: `test.${data.uri.split(".")[1]}`,
        };
        handleUpload(newFile);
      }
      console.log("Hola");
    } else {
      alert("You need to permit using the camera");
    }
  };
  const runCamera = async () => {
    const { granted } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
    if (granted) {
      const data = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
        mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
        allowsEditing: true,
        Aspect: [1, 1],
        Quality: 0.5, //From the actual image
      });
      console.log(data);
    } else {
      alert("You need to permit using the camera");
    }
  };

  const handleUpload = (image) => {
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append("file", image);
    data.append("upload_preset", "employeeApp");
    data.append("cloud_name", "omar1");
    fetch("https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/omar1/image/upload", {
      method: "post",
      body: data,
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      });
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.root}>
      <TextInput
        label="Name"
        // value={name}
        mode="outlined"
        theme={theme}
        style={styles.textInputStyle}
        onChangeText={(text) => setName({ text })}
      />
      <TextInput
        label="Email"
        // value={email}
        mode="outlined"
        theme={theme}
        style={styles.textInputStyle}
        onChangeText={(text) => setEmail({ text })}
      />
      <TextInput
        label="Phone"
        // value={phone}
        mode="outlined"
        theme={theme}
        style={styles.textInputStyle}
        onChangeText={(text) => {
          setPhone({ text });
          console.log(text);
        }}
      />

      <TextInput
        label="Salary"
        // value={salary}
        mode="outlined"
        theme={theme}
        style={styles.textInputStyle}
        onChangeText={(text) => {
          setSalary({ text });
        }}
      />

      <TextInput
        label="Position"
        // value={position}
        mode="outlined"
        theme={theme}
        style={styles.textInputStyle}
        onChangeText={(text) => {
          setPosition({ text });
        }}
      />

      <Modal
        // style={styles.modalStyle}
        visible={modal}
        onDismiss={() => setModal(false)}
        animationType="slide"
        transparent={true}
      >
        <View style={styles.modalView}>
          <Button
            icon="cancel"
            style={{ marginTop: 20 }}
            onPress={() => setModal(false)}
          >
            Cancel
          </Button>
          <View style={styles.btnsModalView}>
            <Button
              mode="contained"
              icon="camera"
              style={styles.btnModal}
              onPress={() => runCamera()}
            >
              Camera
            </Button>

            <Button
              mode="contained"
              icon="image"
              style={styles.btnModal}
              onPress={() => runImagePicker()}
            >
              Gallery
            </Button>
          </View>
        </View>
      </Modal>
      <Button
        icon="upload"
        mode="contained"
        style={styles.btnUploadStyle}
        onPress={() => setModal(true)}
      >
        UPLOAD IMAGE
      </Button>
      <Button
        icon="content-save"
        mode="contained"
        style={styles.btnSaveStyle}
        onPress={() => submitData()}
      >
        SAVE
      </Button>
    </View>
  );
};
```

This is what happens when visiting `"/send-data"`:

```
app.post("/send-data", (req, res) => {
  const myEmployee = new Employee();

  myEmployee.name = req.body.name;
  myEmployee.email = req.body.email;
  myEmployee.phone = req.body.phone;
  myEmployee.picture = req.body.picture;
  myEmployee.salary = req.body.salary;
  myEmployee.position = req.body.position;

  myEmployee
    .save()
    .then(() => {
      // console.log("Employee added!");
      res.send("Employee added!");
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.send("Error: " + err);
    });
});
```

Note that I have tested adding to the database by visiting the link `"/send-data"` from my browser on the same machine. But when using it inside the fetch function and trying to reach it from my mobile, it does not work.

I tried to make a simple get request using the PC's IP followed by the port number and the link and it worked on the PC while it did not work on the mobile phone (and it is connected to the same network).

I have looked at all the answers for this question on stackoverflow and on other websites as well but, none worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot fetch from a local server in react native, I would simply suggest to use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/). You can simply install it on your machine.
go to your terminal and then run
`ngrok http 3000` if you have macOS and you install it with homebrew (brew install ngrok), or if you are using Linux or windows, you can open the terminal inside your download directory of ngrok and run `./ngrok http 300` then you will get an URL of your local server as it is a remote one. Then you can copy this URL and make a post request with fetch (I recommend [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) though) Like so:

```
const submitData = () => {
fetch("https://cksgbsc62ba7.ngrok.io/send-data", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(name, email, phone, salary, picture, position),
})
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => console.log(data)); };
```

Surly we will make your request with no problems. Also you can inspect your incoming requests by going to this link `localhost:4040`.

I hope to you all the best.

Comment: I do not know whether it worked or not as it is showing another error saying: ```Unhandled promise rejection: SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "Employee"```

Comment: Yes I used ngrok URL!

Comment: The best thing is that your fetch has been reached the API this is good but you've got another error _Unexpected identifier "Employee"_